# Given a string of html, how would i search and highlight a word?

Tags: javascript

I don't have access to external libraries of any kind so I have to use pure javascript.

The input I'm getting is along the lines of:

```html
"<html>
  <body>
    <p>Test</p>
  </body>
</html>"
```

The goal would be to highlight the word test.

I've thought about splitting the string by linebreak then doing an includes search on the resulting array to find my keyword, but then I wouldn't be sure about how to add a class/element to the

tag.

Any ideas?

Comment: "I don't have access to external libraries of any kind so I have to use pure javascript." So, this is homework? You know you can look at how external libraries do it for guidance, right?

Comment: At this site you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[mcve]**. I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](//codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Comment: the html will get displayed using angular, but i'm trying to manipulate the string beforehand so all angular has to do is display it.

Comment: You know Angular is an external library, right?

Comment: I do believe that's right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will highlight the first p element but if you have more than one it would be better to use an ID and find it by `getElementById`

```js
p = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
   p[0].style.background= 'yellow'
```

```html
"<html>
  <body>
    <p style="width:30px;">Test</p>
  </body>
</html>"
```

Comment: Thanks Scath. It seems like I'd have to first get the string into the dom before angular displays it and then do something similar to this here.